# jQuery ie issue with on paste (content with break)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to paste a content in an input field (I have to use input field) and get the pasted content to other input. my content is like the following (copy all lines and paste):

```
1234
4567
4321
```

on all browser the following link works fine but IE

http://jsfiddle.net/5bNx4/42/

```
        $editor.on('paste', function() {
var $self = $(this);            
              setTimeout(function(){ 
                var $content = $self.val();             
                $clipboard.val($content);
            },100);
     });
```

when using IE and when paste the content, only the first line (1234) will be appear into the second input. but other browsers you get all the content.

Can anyone help me out here
Thanks,

Comment: This working fine in IE9.

Comment: I cant get it to work even on IE9 . did u notice the newlines?

Comment: Sorry, first I misunderstood your prob, check my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IE fails to handle new line and it will on only paste in the first line and disregard the rest.   ***Replacing newlines characters with space does the trick.***

```
clipped = clipped.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, " "); //replace newlines with spaces
```

To overcome add the below code to your script and this will work fine.

```
if (window.clipboardData) {
    $('#editor').bind('paste', function (e) {
        var clipped = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
        clipped = clipped.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, " "); //replace newlines with spaces
        $(this).val(clipped);
        return false; //cancel the pasting event
    });
}
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/5bNx4/44/) in IE browser.

**Reference:** [Allow Pasting Multiple Lines in IE Textbox](http://brandonpugh.com/blog/2011/10/allow-pasting-multiple-lines-in-ie-textbox/)

**EDIT:** Removed `console.log`

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/5bNx4/46/)

Comment: Thanks man looks good. one question. other browsers such as FF or chrome ignore this block of code right?

Comment: @ComeRun Yup, this won't cause any prob to other browser.  `if (window.clipboardData)` this code is only for IE.

Comment: I can paste all the content in the first input but the second input is empty after the paste. I want the content to be copied over to the second one. dont u have this problem?

Comment: im talking about your jfiddle link. when paste the content in the first input, the second input does not get the content

Comment: @ComeRun I don't find any issue in IE9.

Comment: @ComeRun Oops, I found out the reason, I have used `console.log` which is not suppoerted by IE.  Since I have opened my "Developer Tools" I was not facing this issue. Just now realized remove the console.log line from the jsfiddle.

Comment: @ComeRun I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think IE supports newlines in an 'input'. That means you can't even paste multiple lines into an 'input'. You could use a 'textarea' instead or manipulate the paste before it reaches the input and remove new lines.